# How do I find element that contains specific class value?

Tags: python, selenium

The script is failing to found element if the class contains more values in the class.
For example this class:

```
<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal">
```

I want to find this element only by using class -- `s-access-detail-page`.

By looking for an element like this, I'm getting an error that element is not found:

```
find_element_by_css_selector("a[class*='s-access-detail-page']")
```

Same thing if I'm looking for an element with a class that contains:

```
a-link-normal a-text-normal
```

class on the page:

Parsing URL is Amazon: `https://www.amazon.com/s?k=smart+watches&page=1`
need to get product URLs.

Comment: Can you share the url or more of the actual html? Does it work if you use all the classes in the selector? Have you checked that there isn't a timing  issue or a parent frame/iframe? You can also use find_element_by_css_selector("a.s-access-detail-page")

Comment: there is no iframe and yes if i specify full class it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just the following CSS Selector:

```
.s-access-detail-page
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Try either of this.This should work.

```
find_element_by_css_selector("a.a-link-normal")
```

OR

```
find_element_by_css_selector(".a-link-normal")
```

OR

```
find_element_by_css_selector("a.s-access-detail-page")
```

OR

```
find_element_by_css_selector("a.s-color-twister-title-link")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have a wait in and you can use just a simple class selector

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=smart+watches&page=1'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
links = WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".s-access-detail-page")))
linkUrls = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]
print(linkUrls)
```

---

Comment: i used sleep(10_ before content is loaded, but with selenium wait function i'm getting TimeoutException   `File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: Did you use my code as shown above? it ran for me. You can always extend the wait from 10  to 20.

Comment: yes, your code working, but only one thing. It finds all links across the page but i need search inside the specific block so i'm searching inside `li.-result-item`

Comment: ok. modify the selector. I can't see your proposed modified selector as valid for the page though. You wanted to retrieve hyperlinks with class ..s-access-detail-page. Can you give an example url value you are expecting to retrieve.

Comment: i'm  searching links inside this element `<li class="s-result-item celwidget  AdHolder">`  instead of` in your code i'm passing each li element that is found on the page. After iterating over 3 elements i'm getting TimeoutException. Here is how i do it: https://pastebin.com/PsXcyDdb

Comment: You can use .AdHolder .s-access-detail-page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188821/discussion-between-andrew-and-qharr).